# How do I get a list of all nodes, of all types, in the file?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

How would I go about getting a list of all nodes in the file in Python, as efficiently as possible? I want anything that's a node-- shader nodes, geometry nodes, compositor nodes, nodes yet to be invented in the future... the whole lot.

I'm making an addon that adds properties to nodes via an N-panel in the Node Editor, but I need to scan all the nodes' properties in the file to store some aggregate data elsewhere. There doesn't seem to be one single container for nodes in bpy.data, though. There's one for Node Groups, one for Materials, the Scene with Compositor nodes, Objects with Geonodes... I could just look in all the places they would be, but I really don't want to miss anything, including future features that use nodes.

My best guess going is that I can recursively scan everything in bpy.data to find subclasses of NodeInternal, but that seems rather heavy, and I'd just like to make sure there's no lighter, more linear or straightforward option I'm missing.

Comment: Hello. This should answer your question ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79784/how-to-get-all-types-of-nodes-dynamically?rq=1 Parsing `bpy.types` should be blazingly fast, compared to any other solution that requires iterating over data containers. If you're worried for performance though you should hardcode the values. Parsing a text file will almost always be faster than having to compute things. Less versatile, but faster. You unfortunately can't have it both ways.

Comment: That other answer looks like it'd get all the node _types_, but I want to get all the actual nodes in the data.